# Custom scripts don't load on Elementor Editor

Tags: php, elementor

Good evening.
I'm developing a custom addon for Elementor, to display a grid of elements, that will be scrollable thanks to Slick Slider (https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

The render method works fine and I have the expected results on the frontend. The backend does not show the grid correctly, it's just like it ignores the "slick slider" script.

I figure out that I have a problem with the script loading function or with some code I have to write inside content_template method (but I don't know how to use that method to get my queried posts).

**this is my render function**

```
protected function render() {
  global $post;
  $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
  $num = $settings['post_count'] ? intval( esc_attr( $settings['post_count'] ) ) : -1;
  $idToExclude = 8; // just an example

  $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'offerta',
        'posts_per_page'=> $num,
        'post__not_in' => $idToExclude,
        'order' => 'ASC',
  );

  $Q = new \WP_Query( $args );
    
  if ($Q->have_posts()):
    print('<div class="myGrid slick-active">');
    while($Q->have_posts()): 
      $Q->the_post();

      .. queryed objects ..

    endwhile;
    print('</div>/);
 endif;
}
```

Here "slick-active" is the class that triggers the Slick Slider functionality.

I wonder why I cannot see the correct layout and the arrows and dots on the backend.

I show you also the **code snippet where I register the scripts**, just in case it's useful

```
public function widget_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('tcrs-slickslider', plugins_url( '/vendor/slick/slick.min.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'), '1.8.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('tcrsofferte-main', plugins_url( '/assets/js/main.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery','tcrs-slickslider'), $this->plg_version, true);      
}

public function widget_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tcrs-slickslider', plugins_url( '/vendor/slick/slick.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.8.1', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tcrs-slicktheme', plugins_url( '/vendor/slick/slick-theme.css', __FILE__ ), array('tcrs-slickslider'), '1.8.1', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tcrsofferte', plugins_url( '/assets/css/tcrs-offerte.css', __FILE__ ), array(), $this->plg_version, 'all');
}

public function __construct() {
    // Register widget scripts
    add_action( 'elementor/frontend/after_register_scripts', [ $this, 'widget_scripts' ] );

    // Register widget styles
    add_action( 'elementor/frontend/after_register_styles', [ $this, 'widget_styles' ] );

    // Register widgets
    add_action( 'elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', [ $this, 'register_widgets' ] );
}
```

Do you notice anything wrong with that?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I tried to execute the JS code that triggers the Slick Slider directly from the console (on the backend, of course).
This is the response; it looks like that jquery is not loaded properly

*jQuery.Deferred exception:
jQuery(...).slick is not a function TypeError: jQuery(...).slick is not a function*